# Output a variable from javascript into a HTML table of costs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a table with revenue and profit. I ask the what the revenue and profit are so the variable is redefined as the program runs.
this is the HTML table (I left out the rest of the HTML page to lessen the amount of code in my question)

```
<table border="0" style="width:100%"> 
      <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>Drink</th>
         <th>Revenue</th>
         <th>Profit</th>
       </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td> <b>Mocha</b> </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>
            <p id='grandeMocha'></p>
          </td>
      </tr>


    </table>
```

here is the JavaScript

```
var revenue;
document.getElementById('grandeMocha').innerHTML = revenue
var userChoice = parseFloat(prompt("what is the revenue?"));
var revenue = userChoice;
```

Everything works as expected except the table says undefined where the revenue variable should be.

Comment: Perhaps change the inner html after revenue holds the correct value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the reason why it's not showing is because the order that you declared the variables. Try this

```
var revenue = parseFloat(prompt("what is the revenue?"));
document.getElementById('grandeMocha').innerHTML = revenue
```

Comment: Great, well you mark this as the answer if you'd like

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the value from the prompt before you assign it to the html.  It will not update the HTML on its own when you update that variable’s value.  For that you want something like React.  Just get the value from the prompt before assigning to the HTML.